# WebView2, expose JavaScript API under window instead of window.chrome.webview.hostObjects

Tags: c#, webview2

When using WebView2 it's possible to call C# methods from JavaScript on the web page by exposing a C# class in WebView2 under window.chrome.webview.hostObjects.sync.NameOfMyApiInterface.

Where you can name the NameOfMyApiInterface what ever you like using:
`this.MyWebView2Control.CoreWebView2.AddHostObjectToScript("NameOfMyApiInterface", this);`

But I've seen those using other 3rd party Chromium browser plugins putting their API directly under window, like `window.NameOfMyApiInterface`.

Is this possible using WebView2?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Although calls to `CoreWebView2.AddHostObjectToScript` will create proxy objects in script on `chrome.webview.hostObjects`, you can copy those objects wherever you like. You can make a property on `window` and have it point to the same proxy object.

For example, if you have an object `NameOfMyApiInterface` that has a property named `Property` with value `"Example"`:

```js
console.log(chrome.webview.hostObjects.sync.NameOfMyApiInterface.Property); // 'Example'
window.NameOfMyApiInterface = chrome.webview.hostObjects.sync.NameOfMyApiInterface;
console.log(window.NameOfMyApiInterface.Property); // 'Example'
```

If you call `CoreWebView2.AddHostObjectToScript` before navigating to the page that will use `NameOfMyApiInterface`, you can update that page to do the assignment at the top before other script runs. Or if you don't own or can't update the page, you can use `CoreWebView2.AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync` to add the line of script that does the assignment to run before any other script in that page.